# Generate string with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, html

I have a string like below,

```
var markup = "<p class='error-info-popup-link' onclick='processData.getErrorInfoPopup("+helper.qaConstants[item.errors[i]]+", "+item.source+", "+ seqNo +")'> Info </p>"
```

Above string output is:-

```
<p class="error-info-popup-link" onclick="processData.getErrorInfoPopup(Numeric Mismatch, 1, 2)"> Info </p>
```

I want below output:-

```
<p class="error-info-popup-link" onclick="processData.getErrorInfoPopup('Numeric Mismatch', 1, 2)"> Info </p>
```

What should i do?

Comment: You can use `\"` to escape quotes in a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the escaped quotes:

```
var markup = "<p class='error-info-popup-link' onclick='processData.getErrorInfoPopup(\""+helper.qaConstants[item.errors[i]]+"\", "+item.source+", "+ seqNo +")'> Info </p>"
```

Or use templates:

```
var markup = `<p class='error-info-popup-link' onclick='processData.getErrorInfoPopup("${helper.qaConstants[item.errors[i]]}", ${item.source}, ${seqNo})'> Info </p>`
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would say bypass the issue entirely and avoid inline bindings.

```
var newP = document.createElement('p');

newP.classList.add('error-info-popup-link');
newP.innerText = ' Info ';
newP.addEventListener('click', function(){
  processData.getErrorInfoPopup(
    helper.qaConstants[item.errors[i]],
    item.source,
    seqNo
  );
});
```